# DevDemon Forms Email Route - Act as email switch and form feature switch?

Tags: devdemon-forms

I'm using the latest version of EE and DevDemon Forms. We have a form that works well. Our first field is an Email Route dropdown. This works as expected and sends an email to the correct person depending what is chosen.

We would like to use this same Email Route field for conditional logic as well. When we enable conditional logic on a field further down in the form, the Email Route field appears in the possible fields to use, however, no matter what we enter for "value", the condition is never met.  We've tried to enter the label and the value from the Email Route field, but nothing seems to work.

Is there a way to use Email Route as both a route selector and as a conditional switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the values in the html.

The email route field doesn't use the actual email as the values.

[image]

If you use the actual values from the HTML it will work.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer and worked as expected. (Though enabling this conditional did trigger another error in the Stripe field (Missing Stripe Token!!), which I will post as a separate question. Thanks!

Comment: Missing Stripe Token!! was my error. Forgot to add a product!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that without some tricky work. Instead use a regular dropdown and use the emails as values. Then on your email template set your to: email address as that field with {field:my_email_drop_list} and it will send to that person.

As Manuel said it is possible but with the first method an admin would need to know how to inspect the page and connect them. Just depends on who is managing the form.

Brad

Comment: This is possible as per Manuel's how-to below.